# Error while installing MySql Performance Schema

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-5.6

I am trying to Install "Performance Schema Setup" and "Performance Reports" on my localhost in Mysql database using Mysql Workbench. But It's through error `"Error installing sys Schema"`

> `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)`

I have single and only one account with user name `root`, and It has following privileges:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*35D679085FDD506AEB4'
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

How Do I install "Performance Schema"?

Answer (score 0):

% is used when you need to give a user some remote access. Root user, by default has only one entry in the mysql database in the user's table and that is with root@'localhost'.

you can verify this by:

```
mysql -uroot -p
--> enter your pass

use mysql;
select * from user where user='root'\G;
```

if your root doesn't have access on localhost and `Host` column has value %, create another access for root user by:

```
create user root@'localhost' identified by 'password';
grant all on *.* to root;
flush privileges;
```

It must work.

Comment: Hi @danyal-sandeelo, I had user with 'root'@'localhost' previously, but I had changed it with 'root'@'%', and revoke privileges.  Now It is not allowing me to show user. When I am trying to select "mysql" database, It shows me error "ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'mysql'" Now How to correct problem?

Comment: you shouldn;t have changed it directly..create another use with all the permission and try if that works..if not let me know, I will tell you another trick to get it resolved.

Comment: I am trying to access user from workbench, not it shows me "THe account you are currently using does not have suffcient privileges to make changes to MYSQL users and privileges"